# android debugger does not stop at some breakpoints

Tags: android, debugging, breakpoints

My problem is that the debugger stops at one breakpoint and then continues program running without stopping at the next breakpoint, I think the line code break point it stopped at has some problem but it doesn't show any error and continue running.

Code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("solar_settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = prefs.edit();
mEditor.putString("default_device", DataHolder.defDev);
mEditor.commit();
```

Comment: I have a break point at the next line:                                           SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("solar_settings", MODE_PRIVATE);                                                                                              and the direct next line is this                                                                            SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = prefs.edit();                                             and it also has  a break point, the debuggor stops at the first one and skips the second

Comment: You need to add some source to your question because it's not very clear. Add more details to your post.

Comment: I couldn't add an image cause I don't have enough reputation

Comment: Can you paste the link? Maybe I can edit it in your post.

Comment: There is one edit pending by someone else, can you review it? @user2980568